# how to receive unicode string from php through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i need to receive unicode string from php for my project, the best method that come to my mind was using ajax.

```
    $.ajax({
            url: './php_page.php', 
            data: 'action=get_sum_of_records&code='+code,
            datatype: 'json', 
            type: 'post',
            success: function(result){
                $('#block').html(result);
            }
    });
```

and in php_page.php page:

```
    echo '<table id="records" >';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th>تاربخ</th>';
    echo '<th>نوع</th>';
    echo '<th>مبلغ</th>';
    echo '<th>حذف</th>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</table>';
```

but sadly result was:  �����

i used meta tag, contenttype in ajax, etc... nothing

Comment: you need to ensure the **ENTIRE** pipeline is utf-8. e.g. even if your php script properly spits out the right charsets/content-types, etc..., the page that your `.ajax()` is dumping out into must ALSO be utf8.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through MySQL, PHP, and HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through-mysql-php-and-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From the jQuery Documentation:**

```
contentType Default: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
```

> When sending data to the server, use this content type. Default is
>   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", which is fine for
>   most cases. If you explicitly pass in a content-type to $.ajax(), then
>   it'll always be sent to the server (even if no data is sent). If no
>   charset is specified, data will be transmitted to the server using the
>   server's default charset; you must decode this appropriately on the
>   server side.

Also check your file type it must be save in `utf8` encoded, if you are using database, than your table column must be `utf8` encoded.

Comment: i can't believe i did this, thanks for reminding... :)